Windows change audio input/microphone device using python
I am writing Python script to test an IVR call. I use PyAudio to record what the IVR is saying and OpenAI Whisper module to convert that PyAudio recording to text.
I have to set Windows64 sound input/microphone device to VB-Audio output cable. Otherwise the IVR thinks the user said something and does not stay on expected path.
But this results in user reply (using pyttsx3 and pygame) being directed to VB-Audio output cable and IVR does not hear user response.
To get it working I need to change the Windows64 sound input/microphone device to "Microphone Array" before playing user response and then changing the microphone device back to VB-Audio output cable.
How do I do the above step of changing microphone device via Python? I checked PyAudio playing audio file option but that does not have the microphone device selection option (or I missed it). Checked other Python libraries but not sure how to approach this.

import pyttsx3

from pygame import mixer, _sdl2 as devices

import random

import wave

import sys

import pyaudio

import whisper

 

CHUNK = 1024

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16

CHANNELS = 1 if sys.platform == "darwin" else 2

RATE = 44100

RECORD_SECONDS = 15

device_index = 1

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

 

print("----------------------record device list---------------------")

info = audio.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)

numdevices = info.get("deviceCount")

for i in range(0, numdevices):

    if (

        audio.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get("maxInputChannels")

    ) > 0:

        print(

            "Input Device id ",

            i,

            " - ",

            audio.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get("name"),

        )

 

print("-------------------------------------------------------------")

 

print("IVR input1 start recording:")

 

with wave.open("output1.wav", "wb") as wf:

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)

    wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))

    wf.setframerate(RATE)

 

    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, input=True, input_device_index=2)

    #stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, input=True)

 

    print("Recording...")

    for _ in range(0, RATE // CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS):

        wf.writeframes(stream.read(CHUNK))

    print("Done")

 

    stream.close()

    p.terminate()

 

model = whisper.load_model("base")

result = model.transcribe(

    "C:/Users/Documents/output1.wav"

)

print("IVR input1 text is:")

print(result["text"])

 

####################################################################################################

 

# convert text to speech and play the speech file as user response to the IVR prompt

# Get available output devices

print("----------------------record device list---------------------")

mixer.init()

print("Outputs:", devices.audio.get_audio_device_names(False))

mixer.quit()

print("--------------------------------------------------------------")

 

# Initialize mixer with the correct device

mixer.init(devicename="Speakers (Realtek(R) Audio)")

 

# Initialize text to speech

engine = pyttsx3.Engine()

randomRate = random.randint(130, 170)

# Speed of speech (words per minute)

engine.setProperty("rate", randomRate)

text = "John Doe"

 

# Play the audio

#engine.say("John Doe")

#engine.runAndWait()

 

# Save speech as audio file

engine.save_to_file(text, "speech.wav")

engine.runAndWait()

 

# Play the saved audio file

mixer.music.load("C:/Users/Documents/speech.wav")

mixer.music.play()

 

####################################################################################################

 

print("IVR input2 start recording:")

 

with wave.open("output2.wav", "wb") as wf:

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)

    wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))

    wf.setframerate(RATE)

 

    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, input=True, input_device_index=2)

    #stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, input=True)

 

    print("Recording...")

    for _ in range(0, RATE // CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS):

        wf.writeframes(stream.read(CHUNK))

    print("Done")

 

    stream.close()

    p.terminate()

 

model = whisper.load_model("base")

result = model.transcribe(

    "C:/Users/Documents/output2.wav"

)

print("IVR input2 text is:")

print(result["text"])```





